# Java application inconsistent state

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm

I find my entire application messed up. First log got [mingled up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10194791/logging-mingled-log4j). Application seems to be freezing after every regular interval,freezing for almost half a minute after every minute or so.The regular threads which performs majority of task seems to have got lost and they have no traces of theirs.All these are drawn up from the logging. Socket seems to had hanged up as per report of the user.

Still very little clue, what had triggered all these. CPU usage record shows everything fine at that time. As I'm left to guess,can you point out a starting point or any particular instance escaping my mind,hitting which I can decrypt possible reason for all these mess.

Thanks,
Mawia

Comment: Have you checked memory usage? What is the heap limit of you JVM? I mean `-Xmx` command line option.

Comment: If the code is large, narrow down your problem area and post it on here.  I can tell you that regular freezing intervals could be because you are unintentionally delaying a thread, but there is no way to really know if that is true without seeing code.

Comment: System testing/debugging on an unknown system, with unknown configuration, unknown load, unknown test cases etc etc. is err.. 'very difficult indeed' for an experienced developer.  Doing it via a group blog is just... Look, you have to do this.  You have the system, the debugger, the test cases, the documentation, the experience, the logger output, the user reports etc.  We've got 7 lines of text on a group blog.  We can't do anything with what you've given us. Rule of thumb - if you can't narrow down the code where the error is to a size small enough to post, we can't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I experienced such behavior when running java application that uses GC very intensively on virtual box with limited memory. The guest OS did not have enough "physical" memory so it used swap memory. But the swap was on "virtual" disk mapped to the physical disk of host OS.

When java GC running on guest OS started working it had to remove garbage from heap that actually was located on physical disk of host OS.

I do not want to say that your situation is identical but probably it is similar. So, try to check how much physical memory you have and how often is your GC running and how much memory is it attempting to clear. You gave 1GB to your JVM. Do you have enough physical memory? Probably your JVM heap is actually located in OS swap memory, i.e. on disk?

Try to investigate your application. Is there a chance it allocates huge memory and cleans it too often? Is it possible to use cache etc? Check how much memory is used by perm gen and how my by short-living objects.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try attaching to your program with a sample based monitoring tool and see what the threads and the JVM subsystem are doing?  [JVisualVM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html) ships with the JDK and it's easy to use.

Comment: Ah! That is already attached.But all these has happened in past when no one was their to monitor to the system.